No vaya y sea que la lengua te castigue
The line "No vaya y sea que la lengua te castigue" comes from the novel "Relato de un naufrago" by Gabriel García Marquez. The main character, Velasco, seems to warn or advise another character, Rengifo, with this line.
What does it mean exactly?
The other character, Rengifo, is seasick and he seems to reassure him. Velasco is nervous about the weather, almost like he has a sort of premonition of the impending disaster.
Here is the paragraph (on page 12-13):

Acostado en mi litera, tratando de conciliar el sueño, yo
volví a acordarme de la tempestad. Renacieron mis temores de la noche anterior. Otra vez preocupado, me volví
hacía donde Luis Rengifo acababa de vestirse y le dije: -
Ten cuidado. No vaya y sea que la lengua te castigue

Is the phrase a proverb or something biblical? I looked online but there isn't any reference. Literally, I think it means:

Don't go and that your tongue should punish you.

Rengifo is seasick.

I think it is some dialectal form for the more correct: No vaya a ser que la lengua te castigue (May it not happen that your tongue will punish you), a kind of warning meaning something like: be careful with what you say or it might turn against you.

Me pregunto si será algún espía que le pasaría factura.

@tac. Seguí tu enlace de la RAE. Significa que es un tipo de narrador que observa todo y que va a pagar el pato?

@Bluelion7 No lo sé, la metáfora que usa el autor podría referir a muchas cosas. Todo depende del contexto de la historia. A menos que alguien de acá tenga el tiempo suficiente para leer el libro completo y poder dar una opinión fundamentada, dudo que alguien tenga una respuesta concluyente para este tipo de preguntas.

He has put together two different idioms: No vaya que x and No sea que x. It's quite elegant in fact.

May your tongue not betray or punish you.

@Lambie "No sea que" and "No vaya a ser que" are equivalents. He's not putting two different idioms together. It's just using the second one in an archaic form or dialectal form, as mentioned by Gustavson.

@RubioRic Where's the proof of that? They may be equivalent but he has put them together. He says he thinks it's dialectal. thinks.

@Lambie Yes, he thinks, you think, I think. I think that it's a good hypothesis and that makes sense, that what I'm saying. Don't really now where or when that variant is used. It's not relevant for interpreting the text and answer the question

@Lambie As an impersonal structure, "no vaya que" does not work at all in Spanish, "no sea que" does.

Your quote is missing a relevant part

-¿Todavía no te has mareado? Le respondí que no. Rengifo dijo, entonces:
-Dentro de dos o tres horas te veré con la lengua afuera.
-Así te veré yo a ti -le dije. Y él respondió:
-El día que yo me maree, ese día se marea el mar.
Acostado en mi litera, tratando de conciliar el sueño, yo volví a
acordarme de la tempestad. Renacieron mis temores de la noche
anterior. Otra vez preocupado, me volví hacía donde Luis Rengifo
acababa de vestirse y le dije:
-Ten cuidado. No vaya y sea que la lengua te castigue.

I have highlighted the two related sentences. As far as I can see in these sentences and in the surroundings parts, Rengifo is not seasick.
I agree with what Gustavson has pointed in the comments

No vaya y sea que la lengua te castigue

is equivalent to

No vaya a ser que la lengua te castigue

that can be translated as

It may happen that your tongue punish you

In this case, your tongue is a metaphor for "what you said". The whole sentence reflects the superstition regarding that something bad or evil may happen if you mention it. You can find the same superstition in Harry Potter's books when they use "He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named" for referring to Voldemort. So what Velasco is saying to Rengifo is that he shouldn't mention a weather in which the sea gets seasick (whatever that means) because it may happen.
As far as I know that sentence is not taken from the bible nor is an idiom or a saying. It's not a refrán. And it got nothing to do with other meanings in Spanish of the word lengua, like spy.

No, it is not may happen that. If anything, it's Don't let your tongue punish or betray you. For example.

@Lambie I was not offering the equivalent idiom in English but an aproximate translation of "no vaya a ser". In Spanish such expression contains uncertainty. Is that uncertainty present in your translation?

This could be a comment but I decided to make it an additional reply considering its value to support my claim that "no vaya y sea" is dialectal and, indirectly, its value to help clear things up for OP and for some skeptical users (notice that "no vaya y sea" is considered a Colombian colloquialism, and that García Márquez is Colombian!):

Source

Tal cual Gustavson dice. Esa frase es un refrán que se dice comúnmente y puede significar que debes tener cuidado con lo que dices, pues luego puede ser usado en tu contra, como sucede comúnmente en un juicio.
Que lo que dices puede afectarte luego, algo similar al refrán inconcluso "El que escupe hacia arriba..." o también puede asemejarse al refrán: "El pez por su boca muere".

Great new phrases for me. .In English, there are slightly similar phrases''Keep your words short and sweet.You never know when you will have to eat them''.  Or,''Mend your speech a little lest it may mar your fortunes'' and ''Give thy thoughts no tongue'' and''Give every man thy ear but few thy tongue''.The last 3 are from Shakespeare

Give thy thoughts no tongue (No le des lengua a tus pensamientos) me parece una excelente frase

@RubioRic. Yes, it makes sense that one shouldn't mention something in case it happens or comes back to haunt you. I think it creates a sense of foreboding coincidentally like Shakespeare often did

@En Colombia. Yes, I am sure that you are 100 per cent correct.

Ahora es mi turno de opinar. Como dije, sólo teniendo el SPOILER se puede apreciar por completo la densidad semántica del fragmento así que el que antes de seguir leyendo están avisados.
Lo que hay que tener en cuenta es que efectivamente todo lo que Rengifo dijo en esa parte se cumplió. El autor juega con la ambigüedad del lenguaje.

-Dentro de dos o tres horas te veré con la lengua afuera.

Acá lo está de algún modo desafiando. Estar con la lengua afuera es una expresión coloquial que hace referencia al cansancio, a no dar más para poder afrontar una situación. Lo cual en parte es cierto si consideramos que Velasco fue el único sobreviviente; precisamente por eso fue por lejos el que más sufrió de todos porque si ya fuiste cómo vas a sufrir? Al mismo tiempo, la lengua afuera se puede pensar como una especie de burla, es decir, que Rengifo lo iba a ver a Velasco con la lengua afuera pero no en el sentido en que pensaba (cansancio), sino sacándole la lengua porque sería él a quien le tocase un peor destino.
Después, analizando la segunda frase:

-El día que yo me maree, ese día se marea el mar.

El problema que tiene es que no está explicitado el orden de las implicancias, lo cual deja con dos posibilidades:

A) Si Rengifo se marea, entonces se marea el mar.
B) Si el mar se marea, entonces se marea Rengifo.

De nuevo lo mismo que antes: Rengifo lo dijo probablemente pensando en A), pero lo que efectivamente se cumplió fue B) y además el mar se mareó (o sea, se picó), por lo tanto se mareó Rengifo.
En síntesis, la frase de tu pregunta

-Ten cuidado. No vaya y sea que la lengua te castigue.

es una forma de decir ‘tené cuidado con lo que decís porque se te puede cumplir’ pero con el agravante de que efectivamente en ambos casos lo dijo y se cumplió de la forma que no se lo esperaba. Más aun, se puede afirmar que efectivamente fue castigado por ‘la lengua’ que también se puede pensar como esa misma ‘lengua afuera’ que le señalaba a Velasco, o sea básicamente sería castigado por Velasco por no ser capaz este último de salvarlo estando arriba de la balsa debido a que estaba con la lengua afuera por haber remado tanto.
Una vez más, el juego está en qué es lo que se entiende por ‘la lengua afuera’ y por ‘la lengua te castigue’, yo creo que esa lengua viene a ser lo mismo en ambos casos.

Gracias @tac. Se puede decir que el autor es un genio de hablar del sino y del presentimiento. También ,juega con las palabras para efectuar un sentido doble.Creo que hará muchos más ejemplos a medida que avanzo con mi lectura

I would translate it with "lest":
Ten cuidado. No vaya y sea que la lengua te castigue => Be careful, lest the tongue punish you.
